# Can't convert object of type 'function' to 'str' for 'text

Tags: python, opencv

Good day everyone I'm sorry I'm new to python programming sorry if I'm asking this even this is basic or not. Someone can help me with this? The problem is I want to put the data that has been read by my Pyserial from my Arduino temperature sensor but I don't know how.

Here code for the Temperature to pyserial:

```
def tempe():
    import serial
    import time


    ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
    time.sleep(2)

    data =[]                       # empty list to store the data
    for i in range(50):
        b = ser.readline()         # read a byte string 
        string = b.rstrip()        # remove \n and \r

        temp =  string             <= this data here I want to show to my opencv

        data.append(string)        # add to the end of data list
        time.sleep(0.1)            # wait (sleep) 0.1 seconds

    ser.close()
```

And here's the whole code that I want to show in my PutText on opencv:

```
def offrecog():

screen2.destroy() <=dont mind this
screen.destroy()  <= dont mind this
def recog2(img, classifier, scaleFactor,miNeighbors, color, text, clf):
    image =  cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    features = classifier.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor, miNeighbors)

    for (x,y,w,h) in features:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y),(x+w,y+h), color, 2)

        id, pred = clf.predict(image [y:y+h, x:x+w])
        confidence = int(100*(1-pred/300))

        databases = mysql.connector.connect(
        host ="localhost",
        user = "userdata",
        password = "",
        database = "facerecog"
        )

        mycursor = databases.cursor()

        mycursor.execute("SELECT names FROM record WHERE ids= " + str(id))
        datas = mycursor.fetchone()
        datas = "+".join(datas)

        cursor2 = databases.cursor()
        cursor2.execute("SELECT course_year FROM record WHERE ids= " + str(id))
        datas1 = mycursor.fetchone()
        datas1 = "+".join(datas1)

        cursor3 = databases.cursor()
        cursor3.execute("SELECT positions FROM record WHERE ids= " + str(id))
        datas2 = mycursor.fetchone()
        datas2 = "+".join(datas2)

        if confidence>70:
            cv2.putText(img, datas, (x,y+205), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(img, datas1, (x,y+230), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(img, datas2, (x,y+250), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(img, tempe, (x,y+280), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            markattend(datas,datas1,datas2)
            
        else:

            cv2.putText(img, "UNKNOWN", (x,y+205), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    return img

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("C:\\Users\\So_Low\\Desktop\\final_recog\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

clf = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
clf.read("trained.xml")

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, img = video_capture.read()
    img = recog2(img, faceCascade, 1.3, 4, (255,255,255), "Face", clf)
    cv2.imshow("FACE RECOGNITION", img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('!'):
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
screen2.destroy()
```

and I got this error when I run it:

```
File "c:\Users\So_Low\Desktop\Offrecog\offrecog.py", line 97, in recog2
    cv2.putText(img, wew, (x,y+280), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'putText'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't convert object of type 'function' to 'str' for 'text'
>  - Can't convert object of type 'function' to 'str' for 'text'

[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-u4kjpz2z\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

[Done] exited with code=0 in 14.22 seconds

[Running] python -u "c:\Users\So_Low\Desktop\Offrecog\offrecog.py"
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\So_Low\Desktop\Offrecog\offrecog.py", line 136, in login_verify
    offrecog()
  File "c:\Users\So_Low\Desktop\Offrecog\offrecog.py", line 113, in offrecog
    img = recog2(img, faceCascade, 1.3, 4, (255,255,255), "Face", clf)
  File "c:\Users\So_Low\Desktop\Offrecog\offrecog.py", line 95, in recog2
    cv2.putText(img, temps, (x,y+280), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'putText'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't convert object of type 'module' to 'str' for 'text'
>  - Can't convert object of type 'module' to 'str' for 'text'
```

**Even If I don't put the temperature code into function It run the pyserial 1st before the opencv.
Please Help I don't know what to do. Please**

Comment: somewhere you have a function instead of a string ... you probably meant `my_function()` but instead put `my_function` (without the `()` )

Comment: can you post the specific code , and anything else that is relevant to understanding that line, that is present on `line 92` of your `offrecog.py` file? the traceback shows us this..

Comment: wait i'll update the code @a_n

Comment: Nooo it's a def that meant by the error traceback the def tempe():    @JoranBeasley

Comment: try using `cv2.putText(img, tempe(), (x,y+280), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)` ... but it reads 50 lines before returning anything ... maybe something like `tempe();datas_tempe = '\n',join(data)` and use `datas_tempe`  instead of `tempe` ... basically that needs to be a string ... but its a function

Comment: It run but the OpenCv won't Show on screen it just like code running but nothing happens. It's like the tempe(): is only running @JoranBeasley

Comment: please review [mre]. your question contains lots of code, much of it not relevant. don't add "ignore this" to the code, strip it down. -- also please review [ask]. a look at https://idownvotedbecau.se/ might also help in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

presumably you want to sample your temperature 50 times and then return a single value?

```
def get_temp(ser, num_samples=50):
    float_vals = [float(ser.readline()) for _ in range(num_samples)]
    avg_val = sum(float_vals)/len(float_vals) 
    return str(avg_val) # convert to string for open cv
```

then in your opencv call use `get_temp(ser)` instead of `tempe`

where `ser` is a serial instance thats already open

if taking 50 samples is too slow then you can always take less samples  with `get_temp(ser,5)` to only take 5 samples for example  ... if you want the mode or median instead of the mean then i would recommend just using `numpy.mode` or `numpy.median` instead of calculating it (its probably faster to use `numpy.mean` than calculating the average manually)

Comment: Yesssssss!!!!!! A lot of thank's to you Master @joranBeasley It shows the temperature now in my opencv!!!! Wow You are soo amazing You are very genius. Thanks a lot for saving me for this problem I've been working for week's Thanks a lot!!!... it make a little bit laggy but It shows the temperature data now!!! Wow Thanks again bro

Answer (score 0):

Your function `tempe` doesn't seem to be returning anything.
Why don't you try adding `return data` at the end of the function (after `ser.close()`) ?

```py
def tempe():
    import serial
    import time


    ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
    time.sleep(2)

    data =[]                       # empty list to store the data
    for i in range(50):
        b = ser.readline()         # read a byte string 
        string = b.rstrip()        # remove \n and \r

        temp =  string             <= this data here I want to show to my opencv

        data.append(string)        # add to the end of data list
        time.sleep(0.1)            # wait (sleep) 0.1 seconds

    ser.close()
    return data <= try adding this
```

You might have to note that, you can't directly put this list into the `addText` command since `cv2` does not seem to support taking data from anything other than strings. I think you can use a for loop to iterate over `tempe()` using `for text in tempe()` and do whatever you want with it. Again, depends on your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro! It help me a lot